# IQueryable<T> gives different result than a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

If I use Select on IQueryable on my entity framework result I'll get 4 items as a result.

If I use Select on an IQueryable.ToList() I get all 36 items.

Here's code of the function:

```
public ImagesGetModelView Get(int start, int count)
{
    if (count <= 0) count = 9;
    else if (count > ImageHandler.MaxResult) count = ImageHandler.MaxResult;    

        IQueryable<Image> imagesList = ImagesHandler.FetchRangeScore(start, count)
           .Where(m => m.Domain == Database.Enums.ImageDomain.Gfycat);

        //Works using list :(
        //var list = imagesList.ToList();

        //Select all subreddits once
        //Returns 4 instead of 36 if not using the list ...
        //Returns 1 instead of 2 with Distinct() if not using the list
        IEnumerable<Subreddit> subreddits = imagesList
           .Select(m => m.Subreddit); //.Distinct();           

        ImagesGetModelView result = new ImagesGetModelView()
        {
            Items = imagesList,
            Subreddits = subreddits
        };

        return result;
    } 

public IQueryable<Image> FetchRangeScore(int a_start, int a_count)
    {
        return Repository.AllQueryable().OrderByDescending(m => m.Score)
          .Skip(a_start).Take(a_count);
    }
```

Out of the 36 items 2 Subreddits will be distinct. But since only 4 out of 36 are fetched from Select() it only finds 1 distinct.

So is there anything I can do with the LINQ expressions to get correct data so the distinct statement works or do I have to make it into a List before continuing with the Select & Distinct functions?

Edit:
by moving the where satement from the end to the start of the whole query.
It appears to work correctly now. Select returns all 36 items e.t.c... which in turn makes the Distinct work since it can find more than 1 unique value.

```
 public IQueryable<Image> FetchRangeScore(int a_start, int a_count)
    {
        return Repository.AllQueryable()
          .Where(m => m.Domain == Database.Enums.ImageDomain.Gfycat)
          .OrderByDescending(m => m.Score)
          .Skip(a_start).Take(a_count);
    }
```

Comment: Some mock data might help illustrate your point here.

Comment: I would recommend putting seperate versions of your logic (or a second code snippet of what you changed). It can be difficult to follow comments within code that needs to vary (for instance I can't tell if you example is broken or working correctly).

Comment: Is there a reason you are paging before you call distinct? I would normally expect the opposite order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely your `Where` clause is behaving differently in SQL Server than it would in .NET. Specifically, depending on your collation settings and such, it's likely that various `.Domain` values differ only by capitalization or something like that, making them "equal" to Gfycat in SQL, but not in C#.

You can capture the `.ToString()` on your `IQueryable<>` to see what SQL is being produced and try it yourself.

```
IQueryable<Image> imagesList = ImagesHandler.FetchRangeScore(start, count)
   .Where(m => m.Domain == Database.Enums.ImageDomain.Gfycat);
Debug.WriteLine(imagesList.ToString());
```

Comment: I believe you are correct. You made me realise I had a where statement there :) I added it a long time ago for testing and became blind to it. It's quite studly placed when you look at it, but the dataset is 35 subreddits of 1 type out of 36 so I never noticed it being wrong until last night. 


When I moved it to the start of the query I noticed that the Debug.WriteLine()   did not return a subquery anymore and everything seems to work aswell.

Answer (score 5):

It's difficult to be certain without source data, but `Distinct` works differently when pushed to the SQL.

A SQL `DISTINCT` query will pull records where all values are distinct.  When you do a `Distinct` call on a list of objects in memory, by default it will use *instance* equality.  So you may get back "duplicate" objects (objects where all field values are the same), but they will be distinct "instances", so `Distinct` treats them as different objects.

So it depends on what you want - do you want all `Subreddit` values *including duplicates* or do you want distinct *values*?

To answer your question - if you don't want the `Distinct` call passed down to the SQL you can call `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList`, which makes all further Linq queries Linq-to-Objects (`IEnumerable<T>`) queries instead of Linq-to-{whatever} (`IQueryable<T>`) queries, without the overhead of putting the items in a list.

Comment: I only want distinct values no duplicates.  I need the subreddits distinctly separated for the result.